# OpenID: Custom fields as provider

Tags: openid

OpenID can be used to deliver login information, and some more information than that.

Can I as OpenID provider provide 100 custom fields defined by me (as provider) that OpenID acceptors can request from me?

Or can OpenID acceptors only request pre-defined (non-custom) fields?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. See specification:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html#attribute-value-definition

> OpenID Attribute Exchange can be used to transfer any kind of data. If the data contains newlines, is not a UTF-8 string or it is so desired by the parties transferring the data, the data MUST be encoded to a UTF-8 string without newlines.